# Find the coefficient of $x^4$ in $(x-3)^6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I do not have much experience with the binomial theorem, but I am preparing for CSET exam.

I do not understand the answer: $135$

The $k=2$ term is:

$ \binom{6}{2} x^{6-2}(-3)^{2} = 15x^4(9) = 135x^4$

I am confused what is implicated from $k=2$ or how we would know to pick this value? another part that I am confused is how does the binomial part yield 15?

Comment: What would you say the value of $\binom62$ is?

Comment: It is referring to binomial theorem

Comment: Have you heard of Pascal's triangle? :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binomial theorem says, in this case,
$$ (x-3)^6 = \sum_{k=0}^6 \binom6k x^{6-k}(-3)^k $$

The $x^4$ term is the one where $6-k=4$, which is the case when $k=2$. Plug in $2$ and you get $\binom62 x^{6-2}(-3)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

The degree of $(x-3)^6$ is 6, and you want the coefficient of $x^4$.  The difference is $2$.  In the binomial theorem, $$(x-3)^6=\sum_{k=0}^6 \binom{6}{k} x^{6-k} (-3)^k$$ So we take $6-k=4\iff k=2$.